# How to count emails sent and received per user per day on Exchange 2003

Tags: wmi, exchange-server

I want to know how much mails sent or received by each user per day. It might be easier on exchange 2010 But I'm using exchange 2003. I guess there're two way:

1. Get how much emails in inbox and outbox of each account. Then do the same thing next day and calculate the different. I can get total items in mailbox via [WMI exchange_mailbox class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa143732%28v=exchg.65%29.aspx). But it doesn't tell me inbox and outbox items respectively. What's more, some pop3 users don't keep emails on server. The total items are alwasy 0.
2. The second way is to parse exchange log. But I have no idea about exchange log. Any script can do this?

Is there a better idea I don't know? Any help are appreciate.

Comment: Exchange 2003 is commercial software.  Wouldn't your vendor be the best source of this sort of information?

Comment: I've tried couples of means but I'm not satisfied with them. Maybe you're right.

Answer (score 0):

This may be overkill, but [MailArchiva](http://www.mailarchiva.com/) is an email archival tool that also provides some metrics and statistics on what it processes.  It will tie in with most mail server software, including Exchange.  They have an "Open Source Edition" that is free for non-commercial use, and they offer a free trial of their commercial product.

Parsing your Exchange log would be a much smaller, cheaper alternative.  But since most of the folks here at StackOverflow probably don't know what an Exchange log looks like, you'd need to post an excerpt here, along with any code you wrote as your first attempt at parsing it.  Add that to your question, and see where it takes you!